# Wrap first letter in paragraph tag in a span tag

Tags: php, html, regex, replace, preg-replace

Here is an example:

```
$str = '<p>"bla" bla</p>';
$search = '_^<p> *([\w])(.+) *</p>$_i';
$replacement = '<p><span class="first_letter">$1</span>$2</p>';

$new = preg_replace( $search, $replacement, $str );

echo $new."\n";
```

It works perfectly. But if the given string starts with some kind of special char such as ", ', it will remove it.
example `$str = '<p>bla bla</p>';`

---

To sum up I want to put the first letter in this `<span>` (given above).

Comment: Are you aware of the [:first-letter pseudo selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp)? A little cleaner than doing it in PHP, I reckon?

Comment: Yeah, just needed some explanation on using regexes. Still learning. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but try adding `\W` (capital W) which matches non-word characters instead of matching zero or more spaces in the search string. That should then match your first letter.

```
$search = '_^<p>\W*([\w])(.+) *</p>$_i';
```

EDIT: to include special character

put it in brackets to capture it

```
$search = '_^<p>(\W*)([\w])(.+) *</p>$_i';
```

or as completed code...

```
$str = '<p>"bla" bla</p>';
$search = '_^<p>(\W*)([\w])(.+) *</p>$_i';
$replacement = '<p>$1<span class="first_letter">$2</span>$3</p>';

$new = preg_replace( $search, $replacement, $str );

echo $new."\n";
```

Comment: Now it takes only the letter, but removes the special character that it's infront of it. `<p>"bla bla" adsas</p>` => `<p><span class="first_letter">b</span>la bla" asdas</p>`.

Answer (score 2):

I usually answer directly to questions and don't do wild guesses, but it seems that the most likely use of your code would be to style the first letter of a paragraph. You can do something like this instead (using a so called pseudo class):

```
p:first-letter
{ 
    font-size:200%;
    color:#8A2BE2;
}
```

[The :first-letter pseudo-element<sup>*­Specs*</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-letter).

Comment: It's not fully cross-browser. For example in IE7 won't work... But I personally like this one solution :)

Comment: might want to swap the latter for an image, depending on what the letter is, so might require more than css to solve, but I agree that css solutions are usually better than scripted solutions

Comment: The elegant and modern solutions are rarely cross-browser. But I guess most of them were, if IE didn't exist. Personally, I am just ignoring this "browser".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the special caracters, you can use the following. I tested it a bit.

```
$search = '_^<p>([\W]*)([\w])(.+) *</p>$_i';
$replacement = '<p>$1<span class="first_letter">$2</span>$3</p>';
```

This works with your example.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = '<p style="bla">"Great!
</P>';
$str = preg_replace( '~(<p.*?>\W*?)(\w)(.*?</p>)~is', "$1<span>$2</span>$3", $str);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way it could be done - http://ideone.com/v5KvL

```
<?php
  $str = '<p>"bla" bla</p>';

  $new = preg_replace( '~(?<=^<p>)(\W*)(\w)(?=[\s\S]*</p>$)~i',
                       '$1<span class="first_letter">$2</span>',
                       $str );
  echo $new."\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to worry about problematic nested `<p>` tags if you don't consume  whole `<p>...</p>` tags while replacing.

No capture groups are needed for this task; just release the opening tag and non-word characters before matching the first occurring word character -- then only replace that single character with the new span-wrapped string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IIFYT))

```
$str = '<p>"bla" bla</p>';

echo preg_replace(
         '~<p>\W*\K\w~',
         '<span class="first_letter">$0</span>',
         $str
     );
```

Note that a closing `</p>` tag is not required by HTML.

[https://html.com/tags/p/#:~:text=The%20end%20of%20the%20paragraph,a%20blank%20line%20between%20paragraphs](https://html.com/tags/p/#:%7E:text=The%20end%20of%20the%20paragraph,a%20blank%20line%20between%20paragraphs).

Also, parsing HTML with is not recommended.  If the input string might have `<p>` tags containing any attributes, then the pattern will need to be expanded.  Regex is DOM-ignorant.  In other words, regex doesn't know the difference between HTML and text that merely looks like HTML.

Answer (score -1):

I think the following should work;

```
$string[0] = "<span class="first_letter>" + $string[0] + "</span>";
```

Comment: *"i didn't try it , but it should work i guess..."* No, it wouldn't. It is not even syntactically valid.

Comment: i'm not the php guy, that was just a theory idea !

Comment: If you you are not a PHP guy, why did you answer the question?

Comment: This is pointless. StackOverflow is supposed to provide answers, not wild stabs in the dark.

Comment: so and what u r commenting here is a good answer ? if u knew it better, then correct my answer, and stop bashing people